# Why does this code work as expected if I use Visual C(Visual Sudio 2022) but doesn't if I use gcc 8.2?

Tags: c, function, char, c-strings, longest-substring

I am new to C and still learning(currently doing some "LeetCode" challenges). I wrote a function that should return the longest common prefix in an array of strings. I tested with a couple different values and all works fine. But a string array `{"aaa", "aa", "aaa"}` will result in "aa" (Correct) in Visual Studio but "aaa" in the gcc version and I do not understand why.

[image: LeetCode Output(uses gcc 8.2 with gcc11 standard)]
[image: My Visual Studio 2022 Output using]

**Here is my code:**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize) {

    char* result = calloc(200, sizeof(char));
    if (result == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t result_length = strlen(strs[0]);
    memcpy(result, strs[0], result_length);
    char* result_end = result + result_length + 1;


    for (size_t i = 1; i < strsSize; ++i) {
        char* ptr_res = result;
        char* ptr_cur = strs[i];

        while (*ptr_res == *ptr_cur && *ptr_res > '\0' && *ptr_cur > '\0') {
            ++ptr_res;
            ++ptr_cur;
        }

        result_end = ptr_res;
    }
    *result_end = '\0';
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* a[3];
    a[0] = "aaa";
    a[1] = "aa";
    a[2] = "aaa";

    char* b = longestCommonPrefix(a, 2);
    printf(b);
    free(b);
}
```

@Chris; @EricPostpischil; @VladFromMoscow;

Thank you for pointing out my flaws. I learned a lot form you all.
I marked the answer from @EricPostpischil as the solution cause I tested it and it worked for this challenge. The answer of @VladFromMoscow is great and it seems a lot better for code I would actually deploy so I will definetly take notes.

For reference here is the working code I submitted to LeetCode and it worked well:

```
char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize) {

    char* result = calloc(200, sizeof(char));
    if (result == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t result_length = strlen(strs[0]);
    memcpy(result, strs[0], result_length);
    char* result_end = result + result_length;


    for (size_t i = 1; i < strsSize; ++i) {
        char* ptr_res = result;
        char* ptr_cur = strs[i];

        while (*ptr_res == *ptr_cur && ptr_res < result_end) {
            ++ptr_res;
            ++ptr_cur;
        }

        result_end = ptr_res;
    }
    *result_end = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Using clang on macOS (x86-64), I get "aa" as well.

Comment: Why are you passing `2` to `longestCommonPrefix` rather than `3`, which is the length of the array of strings?

Comment: If I change that to `3`, I get "aaa" output.

Comment: Your initialization of `result_end` is completely extraneous unless the for loop never executes.

Comment: @Chris: That is correct; the body of the `for` loop will not be executed when `strsSize` is 1, in which case the longest common prefix is the entire first string (`strs[0]`), so `result_end` should be set to its length. (However, it should be set to `result + result_length`, not `result + result_length + 1`.)

Comment: @Chris Okay weird. And yes you are right I should have passed 3 my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
char* result_end = result + result_length + 1;
```

`result_length` contains the number of characters in `strs[0]` before the null character, and `result_end` is used to set the null character later, so it should point to where the null character will go:

```
char* result_end = result + result_length;
```

Then this code:

```
while (*ptr_res == *ptr_cur && *ptr_res > '\0' && *ptr_cur > '\0') {
```

allows the loop to progress until the end of the string currently in the `result` buffer or the current string it is being compared to. That can be further than the longest common prefix established so far. The loop should be limited to the length of the longest common prefix:

```
while (*ptr_res == *ptr_cur && ptr_res < result_end) {
```

Observe that testing for null/non-null characters is not needed. If a null character is encountered in `ptr_cur`, then either `*ptr_cur` differs from `*ptr_res` or we have reached the end of the string in `result`, which `result_end` already points to (initially) or before (if it was updated from a prior comparison).

Also `*ptr_res > '\0'` is an incorrect way to test for a non-null character, as character values can be negative. `*ptr_res != '\0'` is a proper test.

`printf(b);` is hazardous, as it is prone to misbehavior if `b` is mishandled. Also, it is generally preferable to terminate program output with a new-line character. Use `puts(b)` or `printf("%s\n", b);`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues in your code which jump out.

First off, you've called `longestCommonPrefix` with `2` rather than `3` being the length of the input array.

Secondly, within your loops, you never actually modify `result` by writing a new null terminator. You only dereference `result_end` and assign the null terminator to it after the last for loop iteration. This has the effect of only considering the first string in your array which is copied into `result` and what it sees as the "last" string in the array based on the length you pass in.

If the function gets called with `2` you print "aa". If you call it with `3` it considers the last string literal `"aaa"` and finds that between `"aaa"` and `"aaa"`, `"aaa"` is the longest common prefix.

Cleaning a few other things up:

```
char* longestCommonPrefix(char **strs, int strsSize) {
    char *result = calloc(200, sizeof(char));
    if (result == NULL) return NULL;

    size_t result_length = strlen(strs[0]);
    memcpy(result, strs[0], result_length);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < strsSize; ++i) {
        char *ptr_res = result;
        char *ptr_cur = strs[i];

        while (*ptr_res == *ptr_cur && *ptr_res && *ptr_cur) {
            ++ptr_res;
            ++ptr_cur;
        }

        *ptr_res = '\0';
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Clarified language.

Comment: Yeah the 2 instead of 3 was an oversight from me. Thank your for the explanation and clarification. Will test it later.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you declared an array of 3 pointers to string literals:

```
char* a[3];
a[0] = "aaa";
a[1] = "aa";
a[2] = "aaa";
```

but it is not clear why you are passing the second argument of this call:

```
char* b = longestCommonPrefix(a, 2);
```

equal to `2` instead of `3`.

Another problem is using the magic number `200` in the initializer of this declaration:

```
char* result = calloc(200, sizeof(char));
```

within the function `longestCommonPrefix`.

In general the following statements:

```
size_t result_length = strlen(strs[0]);
memcpy(result, strs[0], result_length);
```

can result in undefined behavior because a string pointed to an element of the array can be greater than the magic number `200`.

And the dynamically allocated array pointed to by the pointer `result`  after storing characters by means of calling `memcpy` does not contain a string.

This memory allocation entirely does not make sense because the passed array can contain a pointer to a null string.

Also the initializer of the variable `result_end`:

```
char* result_end = result + result_length + 1;
```

Also does not make sense and again can invoke undefined behavior due to the statement:

```
*result_end = '\0';
```

because the pointer `result_end` does not point tp the memory after the last element of the copied string. That is the array will contain incorrect data. At least you should write

```
char* result_end = result + result_length;
```

And this while loop

```
    while (*ptr_res == *ptr_cur && *ptr_res > '\0' && *ptr_cur > '\0') {
        ++ptr_res;
        ++ptr_cur;
    }
```

You can leave the content of the dynamically allocated array `result` unchanged if the string pointed to by the pointer `ptr_cur` is shorter than the already stored sequence of characters pointed to by the pointer `result`.

And the for loop is inefficient because there is no check that an empty string was already encountered.

Pay attention to that the function is unsafe because the second parameter can be a non-positive value.

And even this call of `printf`

```
printf(b);
```

in general can invoke undefined behavior if the common prefix contains symbols that form a format specification.

At first you need to find the length of the common prefix. And only after that to allocate an array of the required size and copy the prefix as a string in the array.

The function and your program in whole should look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
$include <stdlib.h>

char * longestCommonPrefix( char **strs, size_t strsSize )
{
    size_t commonPrefixSize = 0;
    char *result = NULL;

    if (strsSize != 0)
    {
        commonPrefixSize = strlen( strs[0] );

        for (size_t i = 1; commonPrefixSize != 0 && i < strsSize; i++)
        {
            size_t n = 0;

            while ( n < commonPrefixSize && strs[i][n] != '\0' && strs[i][n] == strs[0][n]) ++n;

            if (n < commonPrefixSize) commonPrefixSize = n;
        }

        result = malloc( commonPrefixSize + 1 );

        if (result != NULL)
        {
            result[commonPrefixSize] = '\0';
            memcpy( result, strs[0], commonPrefixSize );
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *strs[] = { "aaa", "aa", "aaa" };
    size_t N = sizeof( strs ) / sizeof( *strs );

    char *commonPrefix = longestCommonPrefix( strs, N );

    if (commonPrefix != NULL)
    {
        printf( "\"%s\"\n", commonPrefix );
    }

    free( commonPrefix );
}
```

The program output is:

```
"aa"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. The magic number 200 is the constraint of the challenge. Any string can be at max 200 characters long, I should have clarified that. And yeah it was a big oversight from me to pass 2 instead of 3. 
Otherwise I learned a lot of new stuff from your post thanks.